# How to handle influx of [log4j] support questions

Tags: discussion, code-vulnerabilities

For context for people who are not up to date: a very serious security vulnerability was recently found in the Log4j library (logging framework for Java applications). It potentially affects any Java application that uses Log4j and worse yet it does not even have to be your code. If you use or integrate with any existing third party application, you might be exposed to the vulnerability.

Over the past 48 hours, over 50 new questions tagged with [log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/log4j) have been asked, with the recurring theme of "Is product/service/framework vulnerable to the log4j exploit?"

I would think these would be off-topic (at least the vast majority of them), given several are duplicates, several ask for docs with patch instructions, a few ask for sample code to test for the vulnerability, and many seem like tech support questions best suited for GitHub issues.

Is it worth flagging these questions as off-topic? Is it worth editing the [log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/log4j) tag to provide guidance on dealing with questions specific to the vulnerability?

Comment: My suggestion would be to create a canonical Q&A covering the vulnerability, its impact, how to determine if your application is affected, how can I (start to) fix it, etc., and then close all new incoming questions as duplicates of that single canonical. This cuts down the volume of noise, while still giving people the information they want/need. Closing as a duplicate also means that a single gold-badge holder can solve the problem, without requiring a consensus of close-voters.

Comment: Is SO really supposed to be another CVE inventory? If I [search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=CVE-2021-44228) for the CVE the first result (right now) is the [NVD](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-44228) from NIST with a bunch of resources. One of them being [this tweet](https://twitter.com/kurtseifried/status/1470650869494337540) with [this really detailed list of affected software](https://github.com/NCSC-NL/log4shell/tree/main/software).

Comment: @CodyGray That was the Comment box you typed into; I think you meant to type into the Answer box ;-P

Comment: Downvote and close with malice

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to refer them to https://security.stackexchange.com? Security and vulnerability related questions seem off-topic of SO and better suited to that site.

Comment: Security and vulnerability questions that arise from practical programming problems in the context of actual source code are *not* off-topic for Stack Overflow, @mbomb007. Please do not erroneously refer users to other sites. General questions about security and vulnerabilities are probably not on-topic for Stack Overflow, but may not necessarily be on-topic for Security.SE, either.

Comment: @CodyGray I didn't. I simply asked a question.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Handle these questions like you would any Stack Overflow question.

If the question is on-topic, then don't close it even if it's about the vulnerability. If it isn't, then close it like you would any other off-topic question.

Stack Overflow's role in this doesn't change, even if lots of people suddenly discover that their services are now vulnerable. Best way for them to deal with it is to follow official guidance from Apache and *assume* they're compromised, and then triage their services.

I'm going through this at work *just* a week before my vacation and the triage path is helping me keep my head on straight.

Comment: Great answer.  The only thing I'd add would be to be on the lookout for possible duplicates, as a lot of people having the same problem may result in more duplicates than usual.

Answer (score 24):

"IS product X vulnerable to CVE-Y" is a **good** question because

- it's perfectly answerable (with yes, because... or no, because...)
- it's not trivial to check manually (many products contains `log4j2` branched or shaded codebase, so simply looking for the presence of `log4j-core` jar is **not enough**)
- it's relevant for a large number of users
- the statements of the software maintainers cannot fully be trusted (if you read about that particular CVE, the responsible developers have seen all the trees, nevertheless failed to see the forest)

P.S. using tag `log4j` for that questions is **invalid** and **misleading**. The affected product is not log4j (which evolved into logback), but log4j2 (this is how it was renamed after the original developer left). It's simply unfair to Ceki Gülcü to say about 'log4j vulnerability' in that context.

Comment: *"using tag log4j for that questions is invalid and misleading"* - True, but unfortunately the entire world is doing it.

Comment: @Gimby When on Stack Overflow have we cared about the rest of the world? We should be retagging such questions as we see them.

Comment: I take aggressive umbrage to the notion of "is product X vulnerable to CVE-Y is a good question" because that implies that we are somehow supporting their product or somehow able to determine the vulnerability of a given CVE for a given use case.  Even in this circumstance, the triage I'm doing assumes that I'm compromised but being compromised in the context of getting (and logging) specific data from a known and trusted source is different than getting (and logging) specific data from the Internet.

Comment: Regarding the tagging of such questions as `log4j`: I wasn't suggesting using `log4j` as a tag. I was seeing a flood of vulnerability-related questions tagged as `log4j`. There are indeed similar questions tagged as `log4j2` (or both tags). Not much I (or anyone) can do regarding mistagging, aside from updating the tag description to provide guidance, as well as editing questions to have proper tagging.

Comment: But it's not a programming question.

Comment: I disagree with the premise of it being a good question - simply because it's likely to be outdated in a very short amount of time. Any product (that is still maintained) with this vulnerability is going to patch their product ASAP, which will quickly make the answer incorrect. As someone else said, isn't this better off in that product's bug tracker?

Comment: @Shadow you could keep the question and answer valid just by specifying versions

Comment: @DidierL thus multiplying each package that's asked about even further? No thanks. I mean, you're technically right but I still think it's a question better answered by that vendors bug tracker.

Comment: @Shadow just use version ranges…

Comment: A specific code sample would make this question on topic. As you put it, the question is not self-contained as it requires obtaining the source code from an external source. Also the scope of analysing an entire product/library seems to bit for SO.

Comment: @TylerH the purpose of the tags is not to educate the world about the proper terms to use for things. The purpose of the tags is to optimize the results when someone tries using a search engine (whether it's a general Internet search engine, or the built-in Stack Overflow search) to find the relevant information.

Comment: @TylerH we should, but we should also expect that pretty much all questions coming in are going to be wrongly tagged.

Comment: @TylerH Sorry, I meant **we shouldn't** because I agree with you! I need vacation.

Comment: @Shadow you're so wrong! Apache team doesn't appear to tend to remove the vulnerability, only to hide it.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I know the purpose of tags. I'm not sure what specifically your comment is saying... are you suggesting we should leave the wrong tag? That's... *not* the purpose of tags.

Comment: I'm suggesting that we should leave the tag that the overwhelming majority of people would search for if they wanted to find the question, because *that fact makes it the right tag*.

Answer (score 6):

There's [log4shell tag](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/log4shell) on Security SE site, which may be a better fit for such question. Maybe close and recommend searching/asking there?

Comment: No - don't start dumping people to yet another SE site.  Send them to Apache instead.

Comment: but SE's aim is to have all answers to all questions.  If there is a satellite site that is best suited to offering support, I see no problem with making people aware of niche/dedicated communities within SE.  That said, if it's on-topic at SO, then users should not be **required** to post elsewhere.

Comment: @Makoto this would be rude and not constructive. What do you expect them to do there? Mock the incompetence of the log4j2's developers? There are already calling the names out there. Those people should never be granted commit rights in an established open source project first. It's not their fault they're incompetent. It's the fault of those who ignored their incompetence and granted them rights they don't deserve.

Comment: @DanubianSailor And what about all those who used log4j as a library and never checked it themselves but thought, hey cool, something for free, that must be high quality.

Answer (score 2):

The way I see it - a Yes or No answer comes in, maybe showing a *current* dependency scan, and the discussion is closed.

The situation is evolving, and Stack Overflow isn't a replacement for a bug tracker; I say the question should be closed with a comment to redirect to the particular software (or vendor)'s ticket/support-intake system.